# How to get Google Tasks task link?

Tags: google-api, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

Is there any way to get a link to task?
(like tasks.google.com/lists/**some_list_id**/tasks/**some_task_id**)

So, for example, if I have an *task_id* and a *task_list_id* from Google Tasks API and want to have an ability to go to Google Tasks from my app.

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is called the [`selflink`](https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks#resource:-task) field. You can read it by getting/listing the `tasks` resource. If you already know the id of both `tasklist` and the `task`, then you already have everything you need to make the API requests. Feel free to write a comment if you need further clarifications.